# Setting a table row as a range

Tags: excel, vba, row, listobject

Once I have identified a cell of interest via a for loop, how can I then make a range out of the entire table row that contains said cell of interest?
I need help with only this small part of my larger code.

```
'TransColumn is a table column in which I am looking for the phrase "NPD".
'TransCell is my cell of interest, containing the phrase "NPD".

'I want Trans_Queue_Row to be the table row in which TransCell is located.  

                        For Each TransCell In TransColumn
                        If InStr(1, TransCell.Value, "NPD") > 0 Then

                        Dim Trans_Queue_Row As Range
                        Set Trans_Queue_Row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Queue").ListObjects("TableQueue").ListRows

'I know this looks like a weird way to achieve what I'm asking for, but I'm using InStr to support some other elements of my code not displayed here.
```

I want a variable (i.e. - Trans_Queue_Row) to identify the entire table row that contains TransCell.

Comment: I already answered this in your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996550/trouble-pasting-row-to-table

Comment: I've further developed the needed functionality of my workbook (since previous question).  I realize now that I cannot simply copy the entire row from the source table and paste it's entirety into the destination table.  Instead, I needed to identify specific column locations in the source row and map them to specific column locations in the destination row.  The specific column location of the source row may not be the same as that of the destination row.  So I want to start by identifying the source row (per this question), then map the needed corresponding column locations between them.

Comment: @TimWilliams I see in your previous response where you gave variable for source table, destination table, source column, and destination row.  I do not see where any variable was created for source row.  Sorry if i'm missing it.  I need to create a source row variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim TableQueue as ListObject, Trans_Queue_Row As Range, i as Long
Set TableQueue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Queue").ListObjects("TableQueue")

With TransColumn.DataBodyRange
    For i = 1 To .Count
        If InStr(1, .Rows(i).Value, "NPD") > 0 Then 
            Set Trans_Queue_Row = TableQueue.DataBodyRange.Rows(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thank You!  Now that I've defined the source row(Trans_Queue_Row), and I have a destination row(Trans_NPD_Row), how do I map individual cells from the source row to the destination row? I've tried mapping Column 2 from source to Column 1 in the destination via the following...without success. 
`Trans_Queue_Row.Cells(, 2).Value = Trans_NPD_row.Cells(, 1).Value`  

`Trans_Queue_Row.Range.Columns(2).Value = Trans_NPD_row.Range.Columns(1).Value`  

`Intersect(TransCell.EntireRow, TableQueue.ListColumns(2).Range).Value = Intersect(Trans_NPD_row, TableNPD.ListColumns(1)).Value`

Comment: @DaveF are you trying to assign the values of one table's column to another column in another table? As I mentioned previously, post this in a new question, and add all the details including some images to illustrate what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From my answer to your previous question:

```
Trans_new_NPD_row.Range.Value = _
     Application.Intersect(TransCell.EntireRow, QueueTable.DataBodyRange).Value
```

You can use Intersect to find the range common to `TransCell.EntireRow` and the data section of the table/listobject.

Comment: Thank you.  I was not aware of how Intersect works.  I've looked it up.