# Delete row in for loop if meets criteria

Tags: vba, for-loop, listobject

I want to delete a row once I've copied it to another location.  There are lots of posts for this issue; I'm not sure why none of them are working in my specific situation.

```
Sub Transition_Queue_to_Other()

Dim QueueSheet As Worksheet
Set QueueSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Queue")

Dim TableQueue As ListObject
Set TableQueue = QueueSheet.ListObjects("TableQueue")

Dim TransColumn As Range
Set TransColumn = QueueSheet.Range("TableQueue[Transition]")

Dim Trans_Queue_Row As Range
Dim i As Integer

With TransColumn
    For i = 1 To .Count

        If InStr(1, .Rows(i).Value, "NPD") > 0 Then

            Dim NPDSheet As Worksheet
            Set NPDSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NPD")

            Dim TableNPD As ListObject
            Set TableNPD = NPDSheet.ListObjects("TableNPD")

            Set Trans_Queue_Row = TableQueue.DataBodyRange.Rows(i)
            Set Trans_NPD_Row = TableNPD.ListRows.Add.Range

            Trans_NPD_Row.Cells(, 1).Value = Trans_Queue_Row.Cells(, 2).Value

'Now, how do I delete each Trans_Queue_Row after I've copied the info from it to the Trans_NPD_Row?  I've tried several different ways with no success, including:

'Trans_Queue_Row.Delete

'Trans_Queue_Row.Range.Delete

'Trans_Queue_Row.Select
'Selection.Delete
```

Comment: Always go bottom up when deleting rows - `For i = .Count to 1 Step -1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996550/trouble-pasting-row-to-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this Code:**

```
Sub Transition_Queue_to_Other()

Dim QueueSheet As Worksheet
Set QueueSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Queue")

Dim TableQueue As ListObject
Set TableQueue = QueueSheet.ListObjects("TableQueue")

Dim TransColumn As Range
Set TransColumn = QueueSheet.Range("TableQueue[Transition]")

Dim Trans_Queue_Row As Range
Dim i As Integer


            Dim NPDSheet As Worksheet
            Set NPDSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NPD")

            Dim TableNPD As ListObject
            Set TableNPD = NPDSheet.ListObjects("TableNPD")



With TransColumn
    For i = .Count To 1 Step -1

        If InStr(1, .Rows(i).Value, "NPD") > 0 Then

            Set Trans_Queue_Row = TableQueue.DataBodyRange.Rows(i)
            Set Trans_NPD_Row = TableNPD.ListRows.Add.Range

            Trans_NPD_Row.Cells(, 1).Value = Trans_Queue_Row.Cells(, 2).Value

            Trans_Queue_Row.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

*Going from bottom to Up and deleting the Row using `EntireRow.Delete`*